# matplotlib sharey imshow not aligning

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am trying to plot 2 different size images, side-by-side with aligned y-axis, but it is not working. See example below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data0 = np.random.randint(0,128, size=(128,256))
data1 = np.random.randint(0,128, size=(128,128))

fig, (ax0,ax1) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharey=True)
ax0.imshow(data0)
ax1.imshow(data1)

plt.show()
```

And it is showing something like this:

[image: imshow example]

And what I want is that the square image on the left (ysize=128) is made smaller so that the y-axis are perfectly aligned with the image on the left (also ysize=128).

Comment: `ax0.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim'); ax1.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')`  does partly what you want, but zooms into the left image. If you also use e.g. `ax0.set_ylim(-50, 200)` both get shrunk to make all constraints fit.  (You can do `ax0.axis('off')` to hide the surrounding axes.)

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have worked.... but looking carefully, it crops the images. It appears to me that sharey does not work with imshow()

Comment: It seems you need to set the limits large enough to avoid the cropping.  `sharey` would work perfectly with `imshow(...., aspect='auto')`.  With the default `aspect='equal'` there are too many constraints to juggle adequately in every situation.